# "Failed to fetch" 404 Not Found, why?

Tags: apt

```
hdaf@neoLaptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for hdaf: 
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                        
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                    
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                        
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                         
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                         
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                     
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                         
Get:1 http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg [72 B]              
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                               
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease              
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                       
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                       
Get:2 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg [933 B]         
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease                         
Get:3 http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg [316 B]                       
Hit http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                     
Get:4 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg [933 B]                      
Get:5 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg [933 B]                   
Get:6 http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg [316 B]                       
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                     
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                     
Get:7 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg [933 B]    
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg                             
Hit http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                                
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                     
Get:8 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg [933 B]            
Hit http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages                         
Get:9 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release [5916 B]                      
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                     
Hit http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                          
Get:10 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg [933 B]            
Hit http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release                                 
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                    
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy Release                                 
Get:11 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release [49,6 kB]               
Get:12 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources [1290 B]             
Get:13 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages [693 B]       
Get:14 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages [1883 B]       
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release                          
Get:15 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release [49,6 kB]              
Get:16 http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources [1290 B]             
Get:17 http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources [727 B]                     
Hit http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages                  
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted amd64 Packages                  
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages                   
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages                    
Get:18 http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources [3336 B]           
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages                  
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages                   
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages                     
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages                   
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en                        
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en                  
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en                  
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en                    
Get:19 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:20 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages [49,4 kB]   
Get:21 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [18,1 kB]                                                     
Get:22 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]                                                      
Get:23 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                                                       
Get:24 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages [49,1 kB]                                                          
Get:25 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages [18,1 kB]                                                      
Get:26 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]                                                       
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Get:27 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en [20,5 kB]                                                         
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en                                                                               
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                                                                                      
  404  Not Found
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/source Sources                                                                                    
  404  Not Found
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages                                                                               
  404  Not Found
Err http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                                                                               
  404  Not Found
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/source amd64 Packages                                                                             
  404  Not Found
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                
Err http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/source amd64 Packages                                                                             
  404  Not Found
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Err http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Err http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/source i386 Packages                                                                              
  404  Not Found
Err http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/source i386 Packages                                                                              
  404  Not Found
Get:28 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en [10,7 kB]                                                     
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/source Translation-en_US                                                                          
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/source Translation-en_US                                                                          
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                
Ign http*//extras.ubuntu.com saucy/source Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/source Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                    
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                               
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                 
Ign http*//ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                               
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                     
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en                                                                    
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                              
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                              
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                
Get:29 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]                                                     
Get:30 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages [23,6 kB]                                                        
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en_US                                                                     
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en                                                                        
Get:31 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages [4010 B]                                                     
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en_US                                                                     
Get:32 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]                                                     
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en                                                                        
Get:33 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                                                      
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/saucy Sources                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Get:34 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages [23,6 kB]                                                         
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources                                                                               
  404  Not Found
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/source Sources                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Get:35 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages [4033 B]                                                      
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages                                                                        
  404  Not Found
Get:36 http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]                                                      
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/source amd64 Packages                                                                         
  404  Not Found
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages                                                                         
  404  Not Found
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en                                                                     
Err http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/source i386 Packages                                                                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en_US                                                                     
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en                                                               
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en                                                                        
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en                                                               
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/source Translation-en_US                                                                      
Ign http*//archive.canonical.com saucy/source Translation-en                                                                         
Hit http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en                                                                 
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                           
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http*//archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 342 kB in 20s (16,7 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/saucy/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http*//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/dists/saucy/source/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try with the methods mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/62483

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? This output suggests you're on 13.10, which is EOL. The official software sources have been removed, so you can't fix this problem unless you upgrade to a supported version.

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/**dists/dists**/saucy/main/source/Sources

The repository doesn't have such path. You should look for an entry similar to:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ saucy main
```

Notice the end *dists* in the url. Remove all this lines. Or if you want you can use `sed` to fix the lines in one go.

```
sudo sed -i 's/\/dists//g' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```